# How to do conditional operator "if" in Object Initialization

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have a code in which I need to apply conditional in a object initialization.

I'm more concerned about **Equities**
So the object initialization displays data on the pie chart... and I need to do :

*if (scheme.Data.SchemeDetails?.SchemeStatus == "Active") then it must display **Equities** value and so on...
else if (scheme.Data.SchemeDetails?.SchemeStatus != "Active") then it must not display any **Equities*** value on the pie chart.

```
public class DashboardController : BaseController
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            if (!UserIsComplete)
            {
                var userProfileService = GetService<UserProfileService>();
                Context.UserContextCache = new AuthUser(userProfileService.CompleteUser(LoggedInAuthUser.UserProfile.Id));
            }

            var crmService = GetService<CrmService>();

            var member = crmService.GetMember(LoggedInAuthUser.UserProfile.MemberId);
            var memberHoldings = crmService.GetMemberInvestmentHoldings(LoggedInAuthUser.UserProfile.MemberId);
            var scheme = crmService.GetScheme(LoggedInAuthUser.UserProfile.SchemeId);
            var memberStatus = member.Data.MemberDetails?.MemberStatus ?? "Active member";


            var model = new DashboardViewModel()
            {
                SchemeName = scheme.Data.SchemeDetails.SchemeName,
                Assets = new Dictionary<string, decimal>()
                {
                    { "Cash", memberHoldings.Data.MemberCashValues?.Sum(md => decimal.TryParse(md.Value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out decimal cashValue) ? cashValue : 0) ?? 0 },
                    { "Equities", memberHoldings.Data.MemberEquities?.Sum(mh => decimal.TryParse(mh.Value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out decimal equitiesValue) ? equitiesValue : 0) ?? 0 },
                    { "Properties", memberHoldings.Data.MemberProperties?.Sum(mh => decimal.TryParse(mh.Value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out decimal propertiesValue) ? propertiesValue : 0) ?? 0 },

                CanWithdrawMoney = CheckAge(member.Data.MemberDetails.DateOfBirth),
                RetirementAge = int.TryParse(member.Data.MemberDetails?.AgeAtRetirement, out int retirementAge) ? retirementAge : 65,

            };

            if (scheme.Data.SchemeDetails?.SchemeStatus != "Activate")
            {
                //model.Assets
                model.E
            }

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: Are all 68 lines of this code necessary to convey what you're asking about? If not, please reduce it to the relevant parts.

Comment: I reduced it as suggested. Thanks

Comment: no one to assist me? please

Comment: I am not sure what you need to accomplish.  And your code does not compile. Please explain better what you need to do... What does "display equieties" means in the code?

Comment: If i'm understanding you correctly, you could build the assets based on your condition, either including the 'Equities' entry or not.  Then just pass this result to the model you are creating.

Comment: @Phil Cooper...  I think so, but how do I do it in practical term as I'm working on a code I have not written it. Can you please show me some code?

Answer (score 1):

Try this example - it's psudeo code and may need tweaking to compile.

You conditionally add the item to the dictionary then pass the dictionary with the creation of the model:

```
var assets = new Dictionary<string, decimal>
{
    { "Cash", memberHoldings.Data.MemberCashValues?.Sum(md => decimal.TryParse(md.Value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out decimal cashValue) ? cashValue : 0) ?? 0 },
    { "Properties", memberHoldings.Data.MemberProperties?.Sum(mh => decimal.TryParse(mh.Value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out decimal propertiesValue) ? propertiesValue : 0) ?? 0 }
};

if (scheme.Data.SchemeDetails?.SchemeStatus == "Active")
{
    assets.Add("Equities", memberHoldings.Data.MemberEquities?.Sum(mh => decimal.TryParse(mh.Value, NumberStyles.Any, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out decimal equitiesValue) ? equitiesValue : 0) ?? 0 });
}

var model = new DashboardViewModel()
{
    SchemeName = scheme.Data.SchemeDetails.SchemeName,
    Assets = assets
    ...
}
```